# Kube / create deployment with config map

Tags: kubernetes

I new in kube, and im trying to create deployment with configmap file. I have the following:

```
app-mydeploy.yaml
--------
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-mydeploy
  labels:
    app: app-mydeploy
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mydeploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mydeploy
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mydeploy-1
          image: mydeploy:tag-latest
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: map-mydeploy

map-mydeploy
-----
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: map-mydeploy
  namespace: default
data:
  my_var: 10.240.12.1
```

I created the config and the deploy with the following commands:

```
kubectl create -f app-mydeploy.yaml

kubectl create configmap map-mydeploy --from-file=map-mydeploy
```

when im doing `kubectl describe deployments`, im getting among the rest:

```
Environment Variables from:
  map-mydeploy  ConfigMap  Optional: false
```

also `kubectl describe configmaps map-mydeploy` give me the right results.

the issue is that my container is `CrashLoopBackOff`, when I look at the logs, it says: time="2019-02-05T14:47:53Z" level=fatal msg="Required environment variable my_var is not set.

this log is from my container that says that the `my_var` is not defined in the env vars.

what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing you key in the command

`kubectl create configmap map-mydeploy --from-file=map-mydeploy`

- try to this `kubectl create configmap map-mydeploy --from-file=my_var=map-mydeploy`

also I highly recommend that if you are just using one value, create you configMap from literal `kubectl create configmap my-config --from-literal=my_var=10.240.12.1` then related the configMap in your deployment as you are currently doing it.